# User should only see documents uploaded by themselves

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website, where users are able to login in and upload different documents like .docx and .pdf and download them through a search function I've made. The login information is getting stored in my users table containing following:

```
idUsers int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
uidUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
emailUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
pwdUsers LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
```

So when the user are logged in, they are able to upload documents through a regular upload form. The files are getting stored in a files table containing following:

```
id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
usersId int(11) - (Foreign key for idUsers in users table)
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
forfatter varchar(255) (forfatter = author)
size int(11),
download int(11) (for later use)
```

When the user is logged in and uploads a document, the "idUsers" value will get passed into usersId in my file table.

As mentioned I've made a search function, which "spits" out the documents that were found based on the search parameter i a html table. But here comes the problem. When the user is logged in, he/she should only be able to see the documents that they have uploaded, and I can't quite figure out how I can get that done.

I have tried to make it works in some different and probaly wrong ways. I'm pretty sure, that something goes wrong in my mysqli_query. I know that I have to "compare" the idUsers from my users table with the foreign key usersId in my files table. In my mysqli_query for the search function, I'm comparing the word the user typed in the search field, with name, title and forfatter (author). I feel like the way I'm making my mysqli_query is going wrong, therefor I've tried to make multiple mysqli_query, one for the search function only and only for the id and usersId. But it failed aswell.

search.php

```
$usersId = $_SESSION['userId'];

$output = '';

if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] !== ' ') {
        $searchingq = $_GET['search'];

$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id AND usersId AND name LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR title LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR forfatter LIKE '%$searchingq%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($id, $userId, $name, $title, $forfatter, $download);

$c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
   if($c == 0) {
         $output = '<p>No search results for: "' .$searchingq. '"</p>';
   } else {

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
         $name = $row['name'];
         $title = $row['title'];
         $forfatter = $row['forfatter'];
         $download = $row['downloads'];

     if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) AND $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId) {

         $output .= 
                  '
                   <tbody class="tableBody">
                      <tr>
                         <td>' .$name. '</td>
                         <td>' .$title. '</td>
                         <td>' .$forfatter. '</td>
                         <td class="text-center"><a href="../uploads/'.$name.'" download="'.$name.'"><i class="fas fa-file-export"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="delete.inc.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"</a></td> 
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM files WHERE id AND usersId AND name LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR title LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR forfatter LIKE '%$searchingq%'"`  Add a condition `AND userID = Current loggedin userID`

Comment: You should work your queries out in mysql console/phpmyadmin before porting them to PHP. It helps a lot when you are soling one problem at a time. It helps also to answer your question, when you post only the problem SQL, not a bunch of irrelevant code along

Comment: SELECT * FROM files WHERE usersId = ".'$usersId.'" AND name LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR title LIKE '%$searchingq%' OR forfatter LIKE '%$searchingq%'

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Unfortunately the suggestions didn't seems like fix the problem. Documents uploaded by other users are still getting showed in the search result..

Comment: or actually @AmitSahu, you answer actually did something right. But another problem has arrived then. Now the user can only see documents uploader by other users, and not their own?

Comment: and I kinda need the first "id" in my statement, because it's being used to delete the documents in the table ^^

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried your suggestion or answer ^^. And unfortunately it still shows documents uploaded by other users